# Issue with Displaying Images using ContentDocumentLink

Tags: lightning-aura-components, contentdocumentlink

I am having trouble displaying images using Content Document Link in my aura component.
I had used these links for reference:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/04/building-content-rich-visualforce-pages-with-salesforce-crm-content.html

https://www.mhamzas.com/blog/2020/01/09/use-salesforce-files-image-file-on-lwc-aura-or-vf-page-as-tag/

```
<aura:attribute name="Art" type="Article__c[]"/>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Art}" var="val">
 <li class="slds-size--3-of-3 slds-small-size_4-of-12 slds-show--inline-block">
   <lightning:card variant="narrow" class="slds-m-around--small slds-card_boundary detailStyle bg-image">
     <ui:outputRichText class="pname" value="{!val.Name}" />
     <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button_base mg-bt " aura:id="view1" variant="brand" name="{!val}" label="View" onclick="{!c.handleClick}" /><br/>
   </lightning:card>
 </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

I had used this SOQL :

```
select id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = ''

select select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId = ''
```

Comment: Please include your controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below markup code

```
<div class='slds-grid slds-wrap'>
        <div class="slds-size--1-of-1 slds-align_absolute-center indicator">
                    <lightning:fileCard fileId="{!v.selectedFileId}" description=" "/>
        </div>
 </div>
```

selectedFileId -> should be the content document Id linked with contentDocumentlink object and there must be associated content version for contentDocument.

Try this let me know If this works for you.

Comment: Hi @Rahul I had tried using lightning file Card. The license I am using right now is Customer Community Plus User License. So when I am trying to fetch the ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink it shows List HAS NO ROWS FOR ASSIGNMENT TO SObject although there is a file assosciated with it.

Comment: This is the code snippet I am using(Art here is a custom Object Id):                                                  
 public static Id getContent(Id art){
        System.debug('BIRD 4 '+art);
 
}
        ContentDocumentLink c = new ContentDocumentLink();
        c = [select ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = '']; 
        System.debug('BIRD 5'+c);
        ContentVersion v = [select id,ContentDocumentId,Title from ContentVersion where ContentDocumentId =: c.ContentDocumentId];
        System.debug('BIRD 6'+v);
        return v.Id ;

Comment: From your code, I can see that you are getting contentversionId instead of this you should fetch only contentDocumentId.